# Flip card not showing backside in Safari

Tags: html, css, safari, cross-browser

I have made a project web page that has some flip cards on hover. It works completely fine in Chrome, Firefox and Edge. Yet in Safari, it flips but it doesn't show anything on the back of the card. I added some `-webkit` elements hoping that would solve it but it didn't change anything.
[Here is link to my Codepen](https://codepen.io/evakdad/pen/ExwWGdQ?editors=1000).

How can I make this work in Safari?

Comment: I'm on chrome, does not work for me

Comment: @Pauldb but Im on chrome too and looks fine...what could be the difference?

Answer (score 0):

Removed these 2 lines everywhere to fix the issue .. only tested on chrome:

```
   backface-visibility: hidden;
   -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
```

Comment: don't know what the issue was on chrome, but Safari is still showing a white card

Comment: and actually removing that messed it up in firefox ‍♀️